# Why is linter not linting over the template in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, lint, tooling

I cannot get the linter to lint the `template` part of my .vue files. Do you have any input on what I need to change in my configurations?

Overall, I would like the linter to adjust something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
              <h1>Home</h1>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

To this:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Here are my configurations:

```
// .eslintrc
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
}
```

and the dependencies:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "mobile.zmittag",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "i18n:report": "vue-cli-service i18n:report --src './src/**/*.?(js|vue)' --locales './src/locales/**/*.json'",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^9.10.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "fibers": "^3.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.17.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config and how you launch the lint ?

Comment: I don't have access to the webpack config, as I created the project through the vue cli. I start the linter with `yarn lint`

Answer (score 1):

The eslint default command lint only JS files

Try to change your lint command inside your `package.json`

From `"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"` to `"lint": "vue-cli-service lint --ext .js,.vue"`

This should allow eslint to lint your `.vue` files

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it does not work even if I add that extension part.

Comment: @Dominik Does your lint command lint JS part of your single files component ? If yes I though you misconfigured eslint to fix templates, tell me if yes or not and I will edit my answer about this case

Comment: The linter does lint the js part of my components. I think it even lints part of the html, e.g. if I have no ending Tag to an opening Tag it does get displayed. But it does not lint things like having only one tab (e.g. see my example in the question)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vscode` editor then you just need to press `ctrl+shift+i` and see the result as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need a custom vue/eslint plugin. Checkout the [docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#installation) for more info and available rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late ...
I was facing the same thing and noticed "'plugin:vue/vue3-essential'" in the config. Changing it to "'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended'" started linting the template part as well.

```
extends:{
  'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
  '@vue/standard'
}
```

https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#bundle-configurations